# How to remove the inner option of my Try

Tags: scala

How can I remove the option so it is just `Try[Int]` and not `Try[Option[Int]]`?

```
val m = Map("a" -> "1a", "b" -> "2")
Try(m.get("a").map(_.trim.toInt))
>>es17: scala.util.Try[Option[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1a")
```

Comment: regarding your comment: " if there was a way to use flapmap?" do you want to preserve the reason of  a potential failure (Try) or are you interested in a result or not (Option) ??

Comment: What result do you want if you try to get something that isn't in `m`?  Say `m.get("c")`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Map#get` returns an `Option[String]`, but you can use `Map#apply` instead, which will return `String`, in this case.

```
scala> Try(m("a").trim.toInt)
res3: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1a")

scala> Try(m("b").trim.toInt)
res4: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(2)
```

`apply` throws an exception if the key you're looking for doesn't exist, but `Try` will catch it, anyway.

Comment: How can I remove the option if I keep using m.get("a") ?

Comment: @coolbreeze Then just call `.get` on the `Option`. But that would just be adding more code when there is clearly a way to shorten it, _and_ keep the useful exceptions.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to use flapmap?  Your solution works for me, just want to learn of other alternatives.

Comment: You'd really be going out of your way to use `flatMap`. You would first need to convert the `Option` to another `Try`.

Comment: In this particular case, `Map#get` makes sense because you're in a `Try`. For pedological purposes, however: `flatMap` works only on compatible types (i.e. Monads do not compose). One possible solution is using a Monad transformer (an adapter that make a certain Monad composable with others, see here https://speakerdeck.com/gabro/monad-transformers-what-and-why).

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes in more detail about the comment:

> I was wondering if there was a way to use flapmap? Your solution works for me, just want to learn of other alternatives.

As you've probably heard, `Option` and `Try` are monad instances and while monads are handy to represent sequence of computations, they don't compose with other monads. In other words, we can't compose `Option` and `Try`. We need to find a common ground.

The difference in semantics between `Option`  and `Try` is that `Try` contains information about the case when a result is absent.

We can go from `Try` to `Option` using `Try#toOption` effectively loosing any failure information we may have.

If we wanted to go the other way, we need to add this information back: ne need to provide a failure reason when a value is absent in an `Option`. Something like this:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
def optionToTry[T](opt:Option[T], failure: => Throwable): Try[T] = opt match {
  case Some(v) => Success(v)
  case None => Failure(failure)
}
```

With the help of that function, we can rewrite the original expression as:

```
val res: Try[Int] = for {
  strValue <- optionToTry(m.get("a"), new NoSuchElementException("a"))
  value <- Try(strValue.trim.toInt)
} yield value
```

which uses `flatMap` behind the scenes to compose the two `Try` instances like this:

```
val res = optionToTry(m.get("a"), new NoSuchElementException("a"))
                     .flatMap(strValue => Try(strValue.trim.toInt))
```

Note that we could save ourselves a bit of coding by using the unsafe map getter like so:

```
val res: Try[Int] = for {
  strValue <- Try(m("a"))
  value <- Try(strValue.trim.toInt)
} yield value
```

but this version would be computationally more expensive given the cost of handling exceptions in the JVM.